# Uncaught Exception Object #<objectid> has no method 'html'

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I am getting this message

> Uncaught Exception Object #displayusersearch2 has no method 'html'

The code is:

```
<script src="../../javascript/jqueryfunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function uid_id_search_change()
{
    var search=document.getElementById('uid_id_search').value;
    $.get('userdisplaypopup.php?id='+search,userset);
 }
    
 function userset(res)
 {
     ('#displayusersearch2').html(res);
     Uncaught TypeError: Object #displayusersearch2 has no method 'html'
 }
 </script>
            
 <table width="600" border="0">
     <tr>
         <th scope="row"><font size="-1">Book Id</font></th>
         <td><input type="text" value="1" id="bid_popup" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <th scope="row"><font size="-1">Book Name</font></th>
         <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th scope="row"><font size="-1">Author</font></th>
          <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th scope="row"><font size="-1">Publisher</font></th>
          <td><input type="text" value="1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th scope="row">Search User</th>
          <td><input type="text" id="uid_id_search" name="uid_id_search" onkeyup="uid_id_search_change();" />
          <div id="displayusersearch2"></div></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

The id of the div is `displayusersearch2`. The request is sending correctly. I am trying to get the response to be displayed on the div `displayusersearch2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
('#displayusersearch2')
```

You omitted the `$` that makes that a jQuery wrapper call. Without it, this is nothing more than a String literal. The string `'#displayusersearch2'` does not have an `html()` method.

```
$('#displayusersearch2').html(res);
```

Also,

```
$.get('userdisplaypopup.php?id='+search,userset);
```

will fail for any `search` term with a URL-special character in it. Suggest using `encodeURIComponent()`, or let jQuery do it for you:

```
$.get('userdisplaypopup.php', {id: search}, userset);
```